# How to upload images in a specific folder using API

Tags: images, media-library

I have installed wordpress plugins Real Media library, Real Physical Media, and Media file renamed. Using this I am able to physically move images and organize images in the upload folder as per categories.
Both these plugins have API -
https://docs.devowl.io/real-media-library/api/index.html
https://docs.devowl.io/real-physical-media/api/index.html

but they don't seem to provide any option to upload files.

It means for uploading I still need to use the classic Wordpress rest API.
So how do I then physically move the files, do I upload using classic way, and the images get uploaded in the date file structure format, and use a second API call to move those uploaded images? Or directly while uploading itself I can set the destination folder.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @TonyDjukic - I have not even tried it yet. I had to move to another project before I could try something out. But I played with the API a bit, it looks like I need to upload like any other ordinary file, and then move it to the specific folder using the WP plugins I mentioned. I just wanted to know if the WP API directly had something which I might not be aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
Actually in the regular Wordpress API for uploading media
`wp/v2/media`
please add one more form data entry `rmlFolder: <the_id_of_destination_folder>`
That is all, it gets uploaded in the correct folder.

I am posting my code (in Java based on a library not written by me)

[image: Before the patch for supporting RML plugin]

After the patch
[image: After the patch for supporting RML plugin]

Comment: Hello Sri and thank you for providing an answer to your problem. Please don't post blocks of code as images - instead use the correct code formatting tool - [Editing / Formatting help](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help)